# how to vectorize the scatter-matmul operation

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, pytorch, vectorization

I have many matrices `w1`, `w2`, `w3...wn` with shapes (`k*n1`, `k*n2`, `k*n3...k*nn`) and `x1`, `x2`, `x3...xn` with shapes (`n1*m`, `n2*m`, `n3*m...nn*m`).
I want to get `w1@x1`, `w2@x2`, `w3@x3` ... respectively.

The resulting matrix is multiple `k*m` matrices and can be concatenated into a large matrix with shape `(k*n)*m`.

Multiply them one by one will be slow. How to vectorize this operation?

Note: The input can be a `k*(n1+n2+n3+...+nn)` matrix and a `(n1+n2+n3+...+nn)*m` matrix, and we may use a batch index to indicate those submatrices.

This operation is related to the scatter operations implemented in [`pytorch_scatter`](https://github.com/rusty1s/pytorch_scatter), so I refer it as "`scatter_matmul`".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can vectorize your operation by creating a large block-diagonal matrix `W` of shape `n*k`x`(n1+..+nn)` where the `w_i` matrices are the blocks on the diagonal. Then you can vertically stack all `x` matrices into an `X` matrix of shape `(n1+..+nn)`x`m`. Multiplying the block diagonal `W` with the vertical stack of all `x` matrices, `X`:

```
Y = W @ X
```

results with `Y` of shape `(k*n)`x`m` which is exactly the concatenated large matrix you are seeking.

If the shape of the block diagonal matrix `W` is too large to fit into memory, you may consider making `W` [sparse](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/sparse.html) and compute the product using [`torch.sparse.mm`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/sparse.html#torch.sparse.mm).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I didn't find out how to create a sparse block matrix in torch efficiently, could you please give me some help?

Comment: @ThyrixYang I would start by exploring solutions proposed [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/creating-a-block-diagonal-matrix/17357/3?u=shaibagon).

Comment: I've seen that before, but they create a dense tensor rather than a sparse tensor. It seems that there is no easy way to create block sparse tensor in torch now and there are open issues on this feature. Thanks again for your kind help. Your answer solved this problem since I'm not asking for detailed implementation. I will accept your answer latter if a better solution does not come up. @Shai

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this link. Apparently DGL is working on something similar already: https://github.com/dmlc/dgl/pull/3641